# Seemingly Innocent .NET Regular Expression Blows Up Page Response Time 10X

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've narrowed down this expression (in a larger regular expression) as pushing the page response time from 0.7 seconds to 10 seconds:

```
[^\.]{10,}[\.\?\!]\s*$
```

It's intended to detect a sentence that's at least 10 characters long (I know it's not perfect and would benefit from natural language parsing)... but what on earth in this expression causes the page response time to blow up like that?

The Regex itself is not to blame as it has other components to it:

```
private static Regex innerTextFilterEx = new Regex(@"part1|part2|<faulty-part-above>", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Removing `<faulty-part-above>` executes in 0.7 seconds, adding it moves back to 10+ seconds.

Comment: Take out the call to `RegexOptions.Compiled` and try again. You might be surprised by what you see. In a project I was once working on, that was actually the culprit.

Comment: Why not just use the [String.Length Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx)?

Comment: FYI, I'm sure you know that's a .NET regex you're talking about, and not a C# regex?

Comment: This is not enough information. Please post the entire regex you're using. I'm pretty sure that the alternation is killing you.

Comment: This is just a hunch, and it changes the semantics of your regex a little bit, but try this variation: [^\.\?\!]{10,}[\.\?\!]\s*$

Comment: What exactly is the regex being applied to?  That is, are you validating the sentence as a standalone string, or searching for it in a larger string?

Comment: It's very common that an expression on its own will perform fast, but if you add a number of expressions together in an alternation, that they can become very slow.

Have you tried to run part1, part2 and part3 as separate expressions?

Comment: David's suggestion actually fixes it, response time drops back to ~0.8s range. @Alan: the regular expression is being applied to a hundred or so HtmlNode InnerText values.

Comment: There is some consensus here that the alternation is suspect, presumably because it causes large amounts of backtracking. If this is the case, your execution times can be highly sensitive to the length of the string you are matching against. Have you tested this with inputs of various lengths?

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause for this kind of problem is alternations that can match several ways causing the regex engine to backtrack too much. So the first thing is that the context of your "seemingly innocent" expression *is* significant.

Does putting the seemingly innocent expression first in the alternation make a difference? To what extent does the length of the string being searched make a difference?

In particular, pay attention to the quantifiers in the different parts of the alternation. Are there scenarios where part of your subject might match in either part of an alternation. (for example, * can match zero instances of something. Do you need that? Look at the interactions between the alternates.